# ExecuteNonQuery() FormatException

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database and C# to make just simple memo program.

OracleCommand3 has this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO MEMO_TABLE (M_ID, M_DATE, M_CONTENTS) 
VALUES (memo_seq.nextval, :a, :b)
```

I checked parameters dataset (varchar2)... but I can't find any problem.

`ExecuteNonQuery()` keeps throwing a `FormatException` and I don't know why. It seems `memoContents` is the source of the problem.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime currentTime;

    currentTime = Convert.ToDateTime(oracleCommand4.ExecuteScalar());

    System.Console.WriteLine(currentTime.ToString());

    oracleCommand3.Parameters["memoDate"].Value = currentTime.ToString();
    oracleCommand3.Parameters["memoContents"].Value = textBox2.Text;

    System.Console.WriteLine(oracleCommand3.Parameters["memoContents"].Value);
    // System.Console.WriteLine(oracleCommand3.CommandText);

    oracleCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I don't work with Oracle, but your parameters are `:a` and `:b` but you are passing `memoDate` and `memoContents`. That, or if `memoDate` is a DateTime, don't `ToString()` it.

Comment: Please check that oracleCommand4 properties have been correctly set before oracleCommand4.ExecuteScalar().  Also, the field currentTime is not set.

Comment: As a side note: do not cache connection or command objects. Create them when you need them, dispose them with `using`